# Class POD member variable initialization

Tags: c++, c++11

Regarding the following two ways to initialize the POD member members variables:

```
class Trie {
  Trie()
    : isWord_(false)
  { }


  vector<Trie *> child(keyLength);
  bool isWord;
};

// OR 

class Trie {
  Trie();

  vector<Trie *> child(keyLength);
  bool isWord = false;
};
```

Are the two equivalent (performance wise, generated code size wise, etc)?
Is there a current preference?

Comment: They are different things. One for a single constructor, the other for all. Nothing to do with POD.

Comment: @liliscent , in both cases the asker is initializing a POD data type. I believe they want to know the pros and cons.

Comment: I would be disappointed if they result in different code.

Answer (score 1):

I would refer to this article  [Get to Know the New C++11 Initialization Forms](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1852519) for answers.

They are semantically equivalent, as the article states:

> Regardless of the initialization form used, the compiler conceptually
>   transforms every class member initializer into a corresponding
>   mem-init

However there are some things that are allowed by second option which are impossible for first one if we go outside of POD scope. For example: array initialization.

As for current preference, there is always a strong argument of making Your code readable for others:

- If You're working on a big project, stick to whatever form the rest of project follows, don't enforce new ideas where they're not wanted
- If Your project is small, try to talk with other of its end-users to agree on common form if You think one is more readable than other.

My personal preference would still be first option, because with it I have all the information about class initialization in one place (the constructor) and don't have to scroll all the way to the bottom to see if someone suddenly made a default initialization there.

Comment: Agree with what you say but add one deviation: If default initialization can eliminate the need for a constructor, go with the default initialization and leave out the constructor.

Comment: Also if you have many constructors that vary in detail, these in place initialisers are a very convenient form.